# How to load StringTemplateGroups from the WEB-INF directory of a web archive

Tags: java, resources, stringtemplate, web-inf

this question is somewhat related to this question: [StackOverflow: Howto load a resource from WEB-INF directory of a web archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive)

I want to use StringTemplate and want to load my templates via a StringTemplateGroup. Until know I use the method shown in the related question to get single files from  the WEB-INF folder, but as I [read here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t150395-jsf-how-to-determine-the-web-inf-path-of-the-current-web-application.html), it is considered bad practice to load the templates via a path as the application could be inside a WAR file AND I can not use the StringTemplateGroup because of the path.

Is there a way to achieve this that you would recommend? Can I get the entire folder as a stream-like object for the StringTemplateGroup to read or is there a decent (and not so hackish) way already implemented in StringTemplate?

I am somewhat new to Java but willing to learn :)
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property of context paht into JVM runtime arguments,for example, in Tomcat container,you add an argument -DcontextPath=[somewhere] into startup.sh file, and then get the path of context by System.getProperty("contextPath").The context path also can get from -Dcatalina.base in Tomcat.

Comment: This does not solve the issue when the app is inside a WAR file, or does it? And I am looking for a more general approach that will work without modifing the unerlying server. 

I mean - come on, this problem must be somewhat common..