# Loading properties file from WEB-INF folder in a log4j appender

Tags: java, properties, log4j, classloader

We're writing a custom log4j appender for our application. The appender should log its events to a database. Now the problem I'm having is setting up the database connection. Our jdbc settings are in a file called jdbc.properties which is located directly under the WEB-INF folder.

I've tried accessing the properties file using the following code

```
InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties");
```

... but stream results in being null. Any ideas how I can load a properties file from the WEB-INF folder in a log4j appender *without* moving the properties file to another location?

Comment: I think this will look for properties file in the WEB-INF/classes directory. A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive

Comment: I know, hence the comment about NOT moving the file.

Comment: The problem is, that the appender is used, for example, when the server is starting, so there is no session and it's not bound to an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try,

```
 String  path =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/").toURI().resolve("../jdbc.properties").getPath();
 Properties ps=new Properties();
 ps.load(new FileInputStream(path));
```

Comment: The appender is a freestanding class that only extends AppenderSkeleton, there is no getServletContext() method. Do I really have to create a ServletContextListener which stores the context in a static variable?

Comment: @KimL - of course! you may also use `this.getClass().getResource("/").toURI().resolve("../jdbc.properties").toString()` in instance method of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the file via the ServletContext. i.e.:

```
ServletContext ctx = ...
InputStream stream = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties");
```

Okay, just saw, that you don't have access to the ServletContext - forget the answer.

Isn't it possible to add the information for the jdbc connection into the log4j.properties? Why are you seperating the two?

Comment: Because rest of the application is using the jdbc.properties file. Don't want to have the same configuration in two places.