# How can I determine all available ResourceBundles at runtime?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

My Java app has been localised into several locales. For each locale there is a properties file with the translations. I load it as follows:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", Locale.getDefault());
```

I'd like to determine at runtime all available resource bundles. The bundles are in my application's jar file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard method with ResourceBundle class. You may use  ([hackish solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8501516/142822)) - `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource()` method or this.getClass().getResource("/"). Have look at another SO thread having [same title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686435/142822).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring you can try with PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); 
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/MessagesBundle.properties") ;
for (Resource resource: resources){
    logger.info(resource.getFilename());
}
```