# How to load files/properties from WEB-INF directory?

Tags: java, tapestry, shiro, tynamo

It seems that in my Tapestry app, I can't load ini files nor properties file from WEB-INF directory or class path.

I tried several different methods which should load my file but non of them worked.

1. ex

`realm.setResourcePath("/WEB-INF/auth.properties");`

1. ex

`realm.setResourcePath("classpath:wip/pages/auth.properties");`

I need to load properties/ini file in order to use tapestry-security module which is based on Shiro.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the classpath is the way to go.
Put your file in *src/main/resources/auth.properties* then set your *resourcePath* using 
*realm.setResourcePath("classpath:auth.properties");*

Check the *ExtendedPropertiesRealm* and the tapestry-security testapp for an example

- http://svn.codehaus.org/tynamo/trunk/tapestry-security/src/test/java/org/tynamo/security/testapp/services/AppModule.java
- http://svn.codehaus.org/tynamo/trunk/tapestry-security/src/test/resources/shiro-users.properties

Comment: Great mate, thanks it worked like a charm ^^

Still i don't know why it didn't work from WEB-INF :(

Answer (score 4):

Try `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/auth.properties")` or `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/auth.properties")`

ServletContext has to be use from servlet, servletListener etc.

Comment: It doesn't work :(

I'm checking it by:

`InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("classpath:wip/pages/auth.properties");
System.out.println(in);`

`ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()` doesn't work either.

Comment: I fouund old post: [Howto load a resource from WEB-INF directory of a web archive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1108434/651140)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(new File(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/fileName.properties"))));
System.out.println(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way was to

- put file in src/main/resources/config.properties. This will be put in /WEB-INF/classes/config.properties when the project is compiled by maven into WAR
- read the file from a servlet with the following

  InputStreaminputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");

https://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/