# Configuration file not found JAVA EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to load a configuration file. But it doesn't work my configuration file is placed under **WEB-INF** folder

and here is my code to load that conf file :

```
private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "/WEB-INF/dao.properties";
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream fichierProperties = classloader.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);

        if (fichierProperties == null) {
            throw new DAOConfigurationException("file "+PROPERTIES_FILE+ " not found" );
        }
```

I'm always getting this error file not found, Should make some changes on the build path ??

Answer (score 1):

For simple purpose, try

Put `dao.properties` inside `src` folder (where put source code).

Change to

```
private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "dao.properties";  //  <-------
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();    
InputStream fichierProperties = classloader.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);

if (fichierProperties == null) {
    throw new DAOConfigurationException("file "+PROPERTIES_FILE+ " not found" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! but my configuration file will be in a safe place in the src folder ?

Comment: use `classpath:` (you search Google for example use `classpath` with keyword: `java classpath properties`). I looking for a nice example for you: http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663564/how-to-load-files-properties-from-web-inf-directory?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you put your file inside the WEB-INF directory, You can use context object to read your file as shown if you have access to servlet context

```
InputStream input = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/dao.properties");
```