# Having trouble locating (connecting to) a database using relative path

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I am having trouble accessing my database on a server.  I am using code snippet this to try to connect.

```
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
String currdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("EPIC currentDir = " + currentDir);
System.out.println("EPIC currdir = " + currdir);
String builder = "jdbc:sqlite:"+ currentDir +"dbname";
```

Now.. the printlns are telling me that:

```
currentDir = /usr/local/cpanel/base/.
currdir = /usr/local/cpanel/base
```

and I know that this is going to give SQLException because my db is located in 
    ../WEB-INF/lib/dbname
So no surprise that I get this error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: opening db: '/usr/local/cpanel/base/.dbname': Permission denied
```

So my question is this.. what is after base and how does that relate to my directory (from  where the servlet is run)? I don't have SSH to go looking for it (rolls eyes) and if anyone can shed some light on the subject I would be greatful!
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Weird stuff

I am testing all this with these commands..

```
String currentDir = new File("dbname").getAbsolutePath();
String currdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("EPIC currentDir = " + currentDir);
System.out.println("EPIC currdir = " + currdir);
System.out.println("EPICER  = " + this.getClass().getResource("dbname").toString());
System.out.println("EPICEST!  = ");
```

this is the output:

```
EPIC currentDir = /usr/local/cpanel/base/dbname
```

<< this one gives me "Permission Denied"

```
EPIC currdir = /usr/local/cpanel/base
```

<< this one gives me "Permission Denied"

```
EPICEST!  =
```

<< this is ok.. but wait.. NO EPICER???

```
System.out.println("EPICER  = " + this.getClass().getResource("dbname").toString());
```

DOES NOT PRINT!! what? is my log being filtered to prevent me from viewing the path? Also, none of those paths work :(

<<<<---UPDATE--->>>>

Did not print because "this" was returning null and i was actually getting NPE on this line; thus, no println. duh.

LAST EDIT:
SOLVED!

Ok, so I was going about it all wrong and I'm posting this just in case some other poor guy is about to waste three days like I did..

```
this.getClass().getResource("dbname").toString())
```

"this" was coming back null because what? SURPRISE, no ServletContext
so

```
getServletContext()
```

was also returning null ( something I experimented with later)

I learned from other resources on the internets that the way I was going about doing this was all wrong because, every time I re-deploy the WAR file, the DB will be overwritten.. so I created a little directory in my /home/username/ called dbfiles and used the commands:

```
String dir= "jdbc:sqlite:/home/username/dbfiles/dbname.db";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dir);
```

and it works!!

Thanks everyone

Comment: Error says "Permission denied", so i don't think there is any issue with the path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto load a resource from WEB-INF directory of a web archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive)

Comment: aah, so it finds the database but does not have permission to read/write?

Comment: Holy cow, thanks Snicolas! I have been looking for a few days for that answer!!!

Comment: Well, after some testing.. weird stuff going on.. updated in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

*user.dir* is directory of system user.
If you want to find file inside your application war, then use [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: ServletContext was returning null because I'm a noob.. also I'm using tomcat7 and web.xml (from what I can see with my noobish eyes) is not needed.  However, I did find instances of people putting web.xml in their /WEB-INF/  Why is that? and what does it do?  If you have any resources that spell it out for n00bs like myself please share.  Also, I fixed the problem and it's in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

To access a database from an Applet using JDBC (read-only):

I made a connection similar to the one listed here http://www.shoaibinamdar.in/blog/?p=313 but insread of

```
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite::resource:"+
    getClass().getResource("sample.db").toString());
```

I put

```
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:resource/sample.db");
```

the sample.db went in /myprojectname/resource/sample.db, with resource being in the same dir (myprojectname) as /myprojectname/src/

Hope this helps someone