# Loading resource under WEB-INF folder

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I've a web application and and XML file in the WEB-INF directory. I need to load this xml file. Is there other ways of loading it rather than using `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/test.xml");`

I tried options like `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/test.xml");`

It is not working.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Q: What exactly is wrong with the "getServletContext()" method?

Comment: I want to load this from a static block.

Comment: duplicate [Howto load a resource from WEB-INF directory of a web archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive)

Answer (score 1):

you can access resources from within `WEB-INF` folder just using `/WEB-INF/test.xml` from within your application (jsp - servlet).

```
<!%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tiles-jsp.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
```

If you want to make it available to a web user then it CANNOT be accessed directly. For a user to access it directly, there must be some sort of interface that will expose the file from the WEB-INF folder (ex. jsp that reads the file  /WEB-INF/test.xml and output's it to the jsp/servlet)

**UPDATE**

To read a file using a Servlet use this:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
    int ch;
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/newfile.xml");
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
                strContent.append((char) ch);
            }
            fin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File " + file.getAbsolutePath()
                    + " could not found");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading the file" + ioe);
        }
        System.out.println("File contents :");
        System.out.println(strContent);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

This will read a file named newfile.xml from `WEB-INF` and will output its contents to the console. The output will be something like:

> File contents :
>
> < a >
>
> < b >xxxx< /b >
>
> < /a >

Comment: I need to do this from a static block in one of my class. I will not be allowed to call getServletContext() from there.

Comment: if you have access on a response object then you can get it like this ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/newfile.xml"); If not you can pass  response as parameter to your static block

Comment: How do I pass a parameter to static block? static{//some code}