# Load config file from a war

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a Maven project that I'm trying to package as both a war and a jar. As part of my application / servlet initialisation (depending on whether I'm running the jar or the war), I need to read a file called `server.ini`. I've put the file in `src/main/resources/server.ini` and am trying to load it like so:

```
System.class.getResourceAsStream("server.ini");
```

However, this always results in `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `server.ini` file should be in the root of a resources directory.

By placing it in the `webapp` you're making the file available via `http`, but you need it accessible on the `classpath`, which means that you should place it in the resources directory.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do: load the config file as a resource so it works regardless of whether I'm running the war or the jar. I've updated my question to make this more clear. However, my attempt to load the file as a resource is failing on both the jar and the war. I'm sure I'm doing something trivial wrong, but can't figure out what it is. :-/

Comment: Are you building with maven? Putting the file in the resources directory will result in it being where it needs to be. If you put it in a sub-directory of resources, then you need to adjust your java line to reference the subdirectories too.

Comment: And now I know what the trivial error is: I needed to preface my filename with a slash, otherwise the class loader was looking in `java.lang`. So this works: `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/server.ini")`

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance `web.xml` or `context.xml` is better suited to what you're trying to do, but...

Try putting `server.ini` in `WEB-INF/classes`, or do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive).

Comment: You shouldn't put anything directly in WEB-INF/classes. Maven will clear out that directory when you tell it to clean and you'll loose your file. That directory is effectively under maven's control.

Comment: But I do agree that you're probably better off using web.xml to configure your server.

Comment: If I was only running this in a servlet container, I could use web.xml. However, I need it to run out of a jar as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was using the System classloader with an unqualified path, so it was expecting to find my `server.ini` in the `java.lang` package.

Since my file is in `src/main/resources`, I should just use the classloader of my current class, with an absolute path:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/server.ini")
```

This works in both the war and the jar.

The "[Preferred way of loading resources in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java)" question has a great explanation of resource loading.