# How do I access the files in WEB-INF folder easily?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to be able to access the jsp and html files in the WEB-INF folder of my web app which is running on a local glassfish server. How do I do this ? I know that it defeats the purpose of security. But, I want to try this.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you want to access it ?

Comment: what you want to access? If it's a HTML/JSP then simply use `RequestDispatcher` Only application can access it. Content inside WEB-INF is not publically visible.

Comment: Use `servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/myfile");`. [Read more...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive)

Comment: @JigarJoshi - I want to do something which will let me access it by simply clicking on the url for 
the web app in glassfish/web server. That is it should open my index.jsp which is inside the WEB-INF
folder. Is there some easy way to do this, like maybe changing some server config or web config for 
this ? I'd prefer not to do something that requires me to modify many jsp's and htmls. Thanks

Comment: @Braj - can you please show me how ? thanks.,

Comment: you mean through web client (web browser) you want to access file residing in WEB-INF ? if so that is not possible

Comment: Have you read the link that I shared you.

Comment: @Braj - thanks. actually, I'd prefer to do it with some config of files like server.xml or web.xml 
instead of programmatically. Is that possible ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - that is what i want to do.

Comment: WEB-INF is protected to be accessed from outside of the application's classpath.  It's a security restriction.  Otherwise, outside users could potentially gain access to your DB credentials, file system information, log files, etc.  The restriction's there for a reason.  Question is, why do you want to break this restriction?

Comment: Read about request forwarding

Comment: The *whole point* of the WEB-INF folder is that it is inaccessible from the outside via URLs. Therefore it is utterly pointless to put .jsp and .html files into it. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/resource-file")` to load the files in Java.

For direct access use some servlet mapping in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>myJSPfile.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configurejsp.html#wp162442 for some more documentation.

Comment: Or `getResourceAsStream() ` as suggested by @Braj :-)

Comment: It was enough for me to use ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/resource-file") thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly read the files inside `WEB-INF`, it is not public web space, what you can do is you can create a servlet which will forward your request to jsp inside `WEB-INF/`