# Cannot locate a file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am loading a client secret file client_secrets.json

```
  InputStream s = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/client_secrets.json");
  InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(s);
  GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
          GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,r);
```

I keep getting null pointers error at line 2, I am now led to believe that the file couldn't be located. My directory tree looks something like this:

```
/src
  MyClass.java
/war
  /WEB-INF
    client_secrets.json
```

Should I use relative path to my java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15900602/2343305)

```
InputStream s = MyClass.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/client_secrets.json")
```