# Can't provide a key.p12 File to connect to Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud Datastore, I am following this tutorial :

> https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/

I am managing to connect and retrieve all the informations I want but I am connecting with options from environment like so :

> datastore =
>   DatastoreFactory.get().create(DatastoreHelper.**getOptionsfromEnv()**
>             .dataset(datasetId).build());

Now I am trying to provide the options programmatically.
As I understood I can do it by modifying the credentials like so :

> datastore = DatastoreFactory.get() .create(DatastoreHelper
>   .getOptionsfromEnv() .**credential**(credential)
>   .dataset(datasetId).build());

Here is how I declare my credentials :

```
String filename = "XXX/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/XXX9f29f.p12";

    credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                        .setServiceAccountId("XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(filename)).build();
```

My problem is that I get a java.lang.**NullPointerException** from this line :

> .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(filename))

My application has read/write access to the file, which is located in the webapp/WEB-INF folder.

Here is my log output :

```
GRAVE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.<init>(Collections.java:1026)
    at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Collections.java:1013)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.<init>(GoogleCredential.java:208)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:368)
    at com.databerries.bidder.DataBaseHandler.setEnv(DataBaseHandler.java:78)
    at com.databerries.bidder.WebServer.lambda$start$1(WebServer.java:75)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: i think you have to provide full path of p12 file. you can find from here how to load resources from web-inf folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now store my key in an InputStream, but I dont get how I can provide the setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File function with a File from an inputStream

Comment: try something like this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/

Comment: if you found the solution please post as answer, it can be helpful to some one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem came from the way I created my credential object.

Instead of creating it from scracth, I now get it from a DatastoreHelper like so :

> credential =
>   DatastoreHelper.getServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccount, filename);