# Spring MVC - unable to access a file at a relative path required by JAR dependency

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jar, filepath, nosuchfileexception

I am working on building a web application around a Standalone JAR application. Essentially the JAR application reads an input file, processes it and generates an output file.

The input file is placed like this, right next to the JAR.

[image]

The code for the JAR application is shown below.

```
public class FileReadWriteApp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        File inFiles = new File("../inputFiles");
        if (!inFiles.exists()) {
            if (inFiles.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Input directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create input directory!");
            }
        }
        Path inputPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("testInput.txt", new String[0]);
        Files.copy(inputPath, new FileOutputStream("../inputFiles/testInput.txt"));

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(inputPath));
        String parsedInput = content.toUpperCase();

        new File("../outputFiles").mkdirs();
        Files.write(Paths.get("../outputFiles/testOutput.txt"), parsedInput.getBytes());

    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Upon executing the JAR in the Command prompt it successfully creates inputFiles and outputFiles folders at one level higher than the JAR file and puts the corresponding input/output files correctly.

[image]

However, when I add the JAR as a dependency in the Spring based web application that I am building and place the input file and JAR file at the same location, it can't access the input file.

In the Spring web application I have placed both the input file and the JAR file as shown below:

[image]

I can even see them come up in the Target folder in the lib directory as shown below:

[image]

In my Spring Controller method, I am executing the `main()` method of the JAR file like this:

```
String[] args = new String[] { "" };
filereadwriteapp.FileReadWriteApp.main(args);
```

However, in the console I see these messages:

```
Input directory is created!
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: testInput.txt
```

I am not able to understand why the application can't find the file `testInput.txt`?

Can somebody kindly guide me regarding fixing this issue?

Is there some specific location where I should place the `testInput.txt` file so that the "dependency" JAR file can access it?

Kindly note that I am not loading a resource from WEB-INF directory from within the Web Application. In my case, I am having issue with a "dependency" JAR loading a resource from a relative path to itself.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto load a resource from WEB-INF directory of a web archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive)

Comment: @JamesJithin, I am not sure if it's duplicate of that question. That other question is dealing with loading a resource from WEB-INF directory from within the Web Application. In my case, I am having issue with a "dependency" JAR loading a resource from a relative path to itself.

Comment: You would need to use the same approach in the dependency jar to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

FileSystems api returns different path , so you need to use classpath to get the file as shown below

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("testInput.txt").getFile());
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Rai. I had to make some edits to your code suggestion to make it compile. Basically, I had to get the ClassLoader from a static context, so I did this: `ClassLoader classLoader = FileReadWriteApp.class.getClassLoader();`. But, the second statment: `File inputFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("testInput.txt").getFile());` keeps throwing, `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I guess, the application is not able to find the file at that path. Where exactly should I place the file to make it work?

Comment: try moving it to web-inf and say /testInput.txt

Comment: I am getting confused. I have two separate projects. One is standalone Java application which is packaged as a JAR. That needs to read some files at a relative path. That project is giving me some Null Pointer Exceptions when I use the `ClassLoader` kind of syntax. There is no WEB-INF folder in that project. First of all I would need to get this standalone Java application to work fine, then I can think of putting the input file into WEB-INF folder... I think we are getting confused because of two separate applications getting integrated.

Comment: This should work for both scenarios, move the file to resources folder and try