# Accessing file resources in SoapUI Mock Service Deployed in tomcat

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui, tomcat8

**Problem in short :** Accessing local `file` in **SCRIPT Dispatcher** with respect to project path i.e., `def file = new File(groovyUtils.projectPath+"/${responseFileName}.xml")`. This is **working fine** when the test is run from *SoapUI* as **Mock Service**. But giving `nothing or empty` for above statement (`groovyUtils.projectPath`) when the same test is run against **Deployed(remote tomcat) Mock Service**.

> **Note:** Here the `responseFileName` is present in the same location(when running SoapUI tool), relative to the `soapui project xml`

**More Details about the problem:**

Wanted to deploy the above mock service in tomcat. So, created war using **Deploy as war** from *SoapUI*, this has created a `.war` file. If the `.war` is extratcted, it shows the following directory structure.

```text
└───WEB-INF
    ├───actions
    ├───lib
    ├───listeners
    └───soapui
```

And the `soapui project xml` is present under `WEB-INF/soapui` directory.

Since, `Script` dispatcher is using `groovyUtils.projectPath`, and `.war` file does not have that `responseFile`, added the required responseFile under `WEB-INF/soapui` directory using 7zip utility. And deployed the updated `.war` file in tomcat which is successful.

When the *test request* is hit to the **deployed mock service**, it is showing **empty response** and the following **stacktrace** in tomcat's catalina.out :

```
17-Jan-2016 10:13:32.356 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.service null
 com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to dispatch using script; java.io.FileNotFoundException: \responseFile.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:91)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockOperation.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockOperation.java:199)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:218)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:113)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
        at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet$MockServletSoapUICore.dispatchRequest(MockAsWarServlet.java:247)
        at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.service(MockAsWarServlet.java:182)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

- How to refer the *resource files* in the `SCRIPT` Dispatcher so that it works in both way:

  a. mock service with in *SoapUI*

  b. deployed mock service in *Tomcat*

By the way, I am  not sure if there is anything wrong in the way it is done.

Using:

**SoapUI Open Source Edition** - *5.2.1*

**Apache Tomcat** - *8.0.5*

**Update:** *what is already tried apart from mentioned above in the short description*

Only the following variables(underlined) are available in **Script Dispatcher** 
[image]

And if you use `context` in **Script Dispatcher**, unfortunately none of the usual methods for **servlet context** working such as below

> No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunContext.getResourceAsStream() is applicable
>
> No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunContext.getRealPath() is applicable

Obiviously because, SoapUI's API for [WsdlMockRunContext](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/mock/WsdlMockRunContext.html) does not have such public methods available.

I believe that there must be a different way which I am not aware and looking to know from the community.

Comment: Maybe you need to access that response file manually from within SoapUI. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder)

Comment: Thank you @user1207289. Tried those, and unfortunately did not help. If you see on top of `Script` Dispatch editor, you would see the available variables `context, requestContext, mockOperation, log, mockService` and `context` does not have any such [methods](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/mock/WsdlMockRunContext.html).

Comment: Not sure if I was clear before, so just reiterating. What I mean was to access response file from within your deployed WS. Get hold of the tomcat `servletContext` and then access file in WEB-INF as described in above posts. good luck.

Comment: Hmm, which is what I am looking for and updated the question with what is already tried. But mocking is done in the script, user has *limited access* to the variables that is provided by **soapUI**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main issue being : `groovyUtils.projectPath` is working only for first use case, and getting ***nothing*** for second use case.

After *lot of trial & errors* and search on the net, [found a hint](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html) in one of the samples and the following approach working to be able to access the local file resource both below use cases as mentioned in the question.

- running as mock service from `soapUI` itself
- deployed as war in remote tomcat

So changed the code (**script of mock dispatcher**) 
**from:**

```
   def file = new File(groovyUtils.projectPath+"/${responseFileName}.xml")
```

**to:**

```
   def projectPath = new File(mockOperation.mockService.project.path).parent
   def file = new File(projectPath.+"/${responseFileName}.xml")
```

> **Note:** file(resource) must be available in the same location 
>   where soapui project file is present on the disk i.e., after creatin `.war` file, update `.war` file and make sure the required file is placed under `WEB-INF/soapui` as that where *soapui's* project xml is available.