# mock service with soap UI how to edit, the mock after deploying the war

Tags: groovy, deployment, mocking, soapui, war

I am new to soap Ui, and have to configure a mock, to mock responses from a**soap service** given some requests.

this is the groovy script to dispatch :

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent)
def idReq = String.valueOf(holder.getNodeValue("//id"))

switch (idReq) {
    case "74":
        context.ResultResponse = "Response_74"
        break
    case "53":
        context.ResultResponse = "Response_53"
        break
    case "37":
        context.ResultResponse = "Response_037"
        break
    case "12":
        context.ResultResponse = "Response_12"
        break
    case "147":
        context.ResultResponse = "Response_147"
        break
    case "90":
        context.ResultResponse = "Response_90"
        break
    default:
        context.ResultResponse = "Response_74"
        break
}
```

Then I deployed it as a war. Some colleagues want to edit the script to add a new mock response.

I don't know how to edit it when I only have the war package.
Has anyone done this before?

Comment: In that it is not just above script change, but also require change to the project and add new response too, right? I believe you need to update the project and redo the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should be able to do it without `switch` block
i.e., replace `switch` block with below statement

```
context.ResultResponse = "Response_${idReq}"
```

You won't be needing to add more `case`.

**EDIT Based on OP's comments**

It is possible to send dynamic response with adding multiple responses to mock service. All you need to do is have single response with placeholder value. Each response is in a file, load the respective file based on data and set that as response. No additional responses, no changes to script.

Comment: thak you for your answer, i will change the script, but in case there is no response with id wanted it will return default, i want to be able to edit and add mock responses to the war.

Comment: @manu, I believe that you are having place holder in the response, not actually different response, right?

Comment: it's actually a completely different responses that i get from the real soap service given some id, the data in the response completely changes

Comment: Ok, actually you could even do that without adding multiple responses.

Comment: how can i do that, or how can my colleague do that when he only have the war, does he have to create a new project in soapUi  and import the war, i don't know if that's possible...

Comment: Yes, that is possible. All you need to do is have single response with placeholder value. Each response is in a file, load the respective file based on data and set that as response. No additional responses, no changes to script.

Comment: You can find some sample code snippet to achieve the same - https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-get-soap-mock-response-from-external-file/m-p/110795/highlight/true#M19159

Comment: suppose i actually begin with 10 responses created, i load the response file given an id in request, how can i add the other responses when they have completely different data which has nothing to do with the id in request ? suppose i have to add 100 other responses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152535/discussion-between-rao-and-manu).

Comment: @manu, is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835395/how-to-access-file-resources-in-soapui-mock-service-which-is-going-to-be-deploye helpful?