# Location of raw resources in Tomcat webapp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a jsp + servlet application, package to war, deploy to tomcat 8.

I know WEB-INF is the folder to store files which are not to be served, only processed at server side: like html or jsp fragments, etc.
I need to store some xmls. Servlets would read those xmls when processing requests.

The question is:

should I store these xmls in the same WEB-INF folder? Or is there a special place for that? I don't want to do it very anti-pattern.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using maven, you could put your XML files in src/main/resources. When packaged as a WAR, they will be placed in the WAR's WEB-INF/classes folder, e.g.

```
src/main/resources/settings.xml
```

Will get packaged to:

```
WEB-INF/classes/settings.xml
```

That way you can read the file using e.g.:

```
MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("/settings.xml");
```

Once deployed to tomcat and it gets unpacked, you can then edit / update the settings.xml in the WEB-INF/classes folder if you need to. Note that the /WEB-INF/classes folder is the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in WEB-INF/, and use the `getResourceAsStream()` method on the ServletContext object, e.g.

`servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/myfile");`

How you get a reference to the ServletContext depends on your application... do you want to do it from a Servlet or from a JSP?

See here: [Howto load a resource from WEB-INF directory of a web archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive)